# Why is the likelihood function of a parameter and a continuous random variable equal to that function raised to the power n?

Tags: probability, statistics

I do not understand why the likelihood function should be equal to the nth power of that function.

For instance,

$$L(x)=f(y_1,y_2,....,y_n|x)=f(y_1|x)f(y_2|x)...f(y_n|x)$$

where $y_i$ for $i=1,...,n$ are continuous random variables and $x$ is an unknown parameter.

In other words, what is the proof for the likelihood function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The likelihood is the joint pdf of $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$, which is the product of the individual pdfs of $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ assuming the $y_i$s are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Given $x$, if you have $n$ independent samples $y_1,\ldots,y_n$, the likelihood function has the above form.

Comment: I edited my question for clarity.